Is that DRF problem? (about URL slash('/'))
I'm posting this question because there's an issue with the URL slashes (/) in Django Rest Framework (DRF).
Following the RESTful API conventions, I removed the trailing slashes from the end of each path in the project's urls.py file to ensure that no slashes are appended to the end of URLs. In each app's urls.py, I added slashes at the beginning of each path, but also omitted slashes at the end.
Additionally, I added the following lines to the settings.py file:
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS = ['urls.W002']
APPEND_SLASH=False

Despite the absence of trailing slashes at the end of URLs, Postman works fine with all URLs, but I encounter a 404 Axios error in the frontend (React.js) at some endpoints (not all). Also, it works well in Safari and Chrome secret mode, but doesn't work in Chrome.
The frontend says that a slash was automatically appended to the end of the URL.
Then I saw the logs with DRF and Nginx, the request came in with a trailing slash at the end of the URL.
How should I handle this issue? Is it a frontend or backend problem?
And I'm using DRF for the backend, along with Nginx and Gunicorn.
